# How to add the disappearance of scroll (niceScroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

How to add the disappearance of scroll (niceScroll)?

http://jsfiddle.net/xmocartx/CdwAP/4/

```
    $(document).ready(
        function() { 
            $(".chosen-results").niceScroll("",{cursorcolor:"#00F"});
        }
    );
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick and Dirty**

You could possibly trigger resize event on nicescroll whenever document is clicked. Something like below:

```
$(document).on("click.chosen", function( e ) {
    $(".chosen-results").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/CdwAP/5/